# Duda con return en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxis

¿La keyword **return** puede retornar valores como **string**, o solo **enteros**?

Comment: Puede retornar cualquiera de los dos

Comment: Puede retornar cualquier cosa sin restricción, lo unico es que solo puede retornar un valor y no varios.

Comment: creo que más bien la pregunta sería si se puede que no regrese nada `return;`

Comment: Pues... hablando en javascript cuando tu pones solo return; así nada mas siempre estaras retornando undefined, mas no se en otros lenguajes... creo que en java se retornaría null si lo pones así.

Comment: @Riven ya que eres alguien muy curioso de Java te cuento de hecho es una pregunta relativamente simple y compleja. en Java si pones return; "no regresas nada", pero el tipo de retorno de la función es `void` que es un tipo de retorno y está registrado como un primitivo (`void.class.isPrimitive();//true`) aunque oficialmente no es así y solo aparece en palabras reservadas,  así que puedes ponerle su wrapper y hacer cosas locas como `return (Void)null;` que aparentemente no tiene sentido hasta que lo ves en programación asíncrona y entonces piensas que es un buen truco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**return** devuelve valores. Es decir, cadenas de texto, números enteros, racionales e irracionales, arreglos, objetos e instancias de clases instanciables. Básicamente todo lo que se pueda guardar en una variable excepto funciones como tal. Es lo mismo para muchos lenguajes de programación. **Aún así puede que alguno tenga excepciones.**

Comment: Para complementar un poco tu respuesta, en aquellos lenguajes de programación que sean de tipado debil puede retornar cualquier valor, pero en aquellos de tipado fuerte solo puede retornar el valor de retorno especificado en el metodo o función.

Comment: De hecho en javascript si puedes retornar una función dentro de una función y clases en sí.

Comment: Ya sé lo de Javascript, es una respuesta para generalizar. Por eso dije "aún así puede que alguno tenga excepciones". Pero si lo desean puedo añadir todas las que quieran.